# What are the options to use range-v3 library on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, c++14, range-v3

The [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library doesn't build with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. What are the options to build it with Visual Studio (e.g. Intel C++, Clang 3.7 with Microsoft CodeGen) or some other IDE on Windows?

Comment: MinGW(-w64) is probably a safe bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and tried;

Visual C++ 2015 (Update 1): 0/3 examples compile

Clang 3.7 with Microsoft CodeGen: 1/3 examples compile (the other two fail with linker and various compiler errors)

g++ 5.2.0 (mingw-w64 via msys2): 2/3 examples compile, the third one fails with an internal compiler error.

clang++ 3.7.0 (mingw-w64 via msys2): 3/3 examples compile

The sample size is rather small and I'm not sure how much of the library they cover, but it looks like clang is your best bet at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I'm installing an eval version of Intel C++ compiler to test with range-v3. BTW, is there an IDE easy to setup and use with Clang version, which passed all 3 tests? Where did you get mingw-w64 clang from?

Comment: [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/) comes with a package manager (pacman), mingw-w64-(i686 or x86_64)-clang is the package you want. I've used JetBrains' CLion(not free), but Eclipse and anything that can use Makefiles should also work. If you do want to use CLion, install mingw-w64-(i686 or x86_64)-make as well.

Comment: Intel C++ Compiler v16.0 Update 1 with `/Qstd=c++14` option fails to build _fibonacci_ and _comprehensions_ samples. I haven't tried _calendar_.